# What kind of non linear model is this? (looks like a "s")

Tags: model, nonlinear-regression

This is the situation.

I have the following data and fitted model (red line):
[image]
The fitted model is non-linear of the type y=a(e^bx). My decision to use this was based on previous research papers.

The residual plot indicates some tendency.

So I was wondering what kind of model could fit the data properly? I draw a fitting curve by hand (blue line) with a model that I think it could be the ideal for this data. Can you please have a look and say to me what kind of model is this of the blue line?

Looks sigmoidal but I am not sure.

Comment: While I'd agree that it looks like a sigmoid, I'd also say I'm afraid having only 6 points renders any serious modeling futile.

Comment: @Sycorax it works after refreshing browser, but jmnavarro is right, it's just 6 points so there is not much to discuss

Comment: Looks linear to me.

Comment: A sigmoid have asymptotes, is there some reason from context to beleive there could be asymptotes?  (You did'nt give any context, please add some)